# Why can't I find or use UrlEncode in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, urlencode, system.web

I have a string that I'd like to encode into the standard URL format. From what I've found, I should be able to do this via the `httpUtility.urlEncode` method, but I don't seem to have that available.

I've added "using" references to both `System.Web` and `System.Net` to no avail. I've also seen other references to server.urlEncode amongst other variants, but I don't see the method anywhere.

I'm using the latest version of C# in Visual Studio 2010. Is the method called something different in this version, hidden somewhere else, or am I completely off base?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By default, new projects in Visual Studio 2010 target the .NET Framework 4.0 **Client Profile**, which does not include the `System.Web` assembly.

You can change the version of the Framework that your project targets in your project's Properties. Under the "Application" tab, select ".NET Framework 4.0" from the combobox labeled "Target framework".

Then, make sure that you have added a reference to `System.Web` using the "Add Reference" dialog.

Finally, add a [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) to the top of your class for the `System.Web` namespace:

```
using System.Web;
```

You'll find the various overloads of the [`UrlEncode` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2x4538s.aspx) in the `HttpUtility` class. Sample code:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: As stated in my question, I have; although I should have code highlighted it so that it's more visible.

Comment: @Sootah: You forgot to tell us what kind of project you've created.

Comment: Just a standard WinForms app.

Comment: @Sootah: Then either you haven't followed the instructions in my answer carefully enough, or your computer is possessed. I promise it works; I tested it. Make sure you're targeting the full version of the Framework, not the Client Profile. It's bitten many programmers before.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm targeting Client Profile in Framework 4.0 and i found this as `WebUtility.HtmlEncode`. i imported `Imports System.Web.Services`.

Answer (score 4):

In .Net 4.5 you can (should?, 'please use' says a Katana comment) use the System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode method.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be named differently since Visual Studio doesn't supply the class or method names, the .NET framework does.

All I can tell you is that the System.Web.**HttpUtility** AND System.Web.**HttpServerUtility** classes contain a method called `UrlEncode(string)`.

Comment: They contain [several other overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2x4538s.aspx) of that method, as well. And `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode` simply calls `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` internally; they're the same method.

Comment: All that System.Web gives me are: AspNetHostingPermission, AspNetHostingPermissionAttribute, and AspNetHostingPermissionLevel

Comment: That would pretty strongly indicate that you're missing a reference to the System.Web dll, or that you're targeting the wrong profile.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7f1y429.aspx (System.Web namespace) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx (HttpUtility class) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx (HttpServerUtility class) Not according to MSDN.

Comment: @TimS: Were you disagreeing with my last comment? You forgot to read the documentation you linked to. Specifically, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) under the Remarks section: "UrlEncode is a convenient way to access the HttpUtility.UrlEncode method at run time from an ASP.NET application. Internally, UrlEncode uses HttpUtility.UrlEncode to encode strings."

Comment: No I was refering to Sootah, my bad

Answer (score 2):

If your project target ".NET Framework X Client Profile",you cannot not use "System.Web",but you can use "Uri.EscapeUriString | Uri.UnEscapeUriString" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, adding the reference was my answer.  But be sure you double check the project, that it is in, if you have more than 1 project in your solution.  I had a solution with 3 projects.  `System.Web` was added to 2 projects but not the 3rd project.

I spent an hour trying to figure out why I couldn't use `HttpUtility` since it was a Reference in the main project.  But I didn't check the sub-projects of the Solution.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I had the same issue. The Framework was 4.0 but the IDE could not recognize System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode method. It did only after I added System.web.dll to all dependent projects too and rebuilt them. Weird...

Answer (score 0):

Because you only see `AspNetHostingPermission`, `AspNetHostingPermissionAttribute`, and `AspNetHostingPermissionLevel`, I strongly suspect (like the other guys) that you're missing a reference.

The best you can do is start a new project, because it's pretty complicated to add/remove references without ruining your entire project.

*[How to: Add or Remove References in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)* (MSDN) shows how to add/remove references. In your case, you should check/add the `System.Web` reference.